# Basis of Kernel of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Given $\theta>0$. Let $H$ be $5 \times 6$ matrix

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 \theta & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
 \end{matrix}\right]$$
Consider the subspace $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^6:Hx=0$}. I know the subspace $S$ has dimension $1$. However, I couldn't find the basis of $S$. Could anybody help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know it has dimension $1$?

Comment: sorry i  was thinking about  dimension of nullspace,for find basis use for example  row-echelon form or something like this

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: yes, using rank-nullity theorem

Answer (score 1):

We perform the row operations:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\theta & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{R_5 \gets \tfrac{1}{\theta} R_5}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{R_i \gets R_{\alpha(i)} \text{ where } \alpha=(15432)}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{R_i \gets R_i-R_1 \text{ for } i \in \{2,3,4\}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{R_i \gets -R_i \text{ for } i \in \{2,3,4\}}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\tfrac{1}{\theta} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is in reduced row echelon form.  So the matrix has rank $5$ and hence indeed the nullity is $6-5=1$, by the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

By inspection the null space is: $$\mathrm{span}\{(1,1,1,1,\theta,\theta)\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

recall  rank-nulity theorem namely

$rank(A)+rank(nullspace)=n$

in your case $n=6$  ,and   what you need it to find rank of given matrix

for find basis of nullspace,this may help you

[Finding the basis of a null space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/finding-the-basis-of-a-null-space)

Comment: Thanks. Matrix $H$ has rank $5$, doesn't it?

Comment: i need matlab call for it to be honest :D

Comment: yes it seems like this,it has rank $5$

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm sure that $S$ has dimension $1$. Actually, I'd like to find the basis for matrix $H$ in $({n \choose 2}-1)\times {n \choose 2}$. And the matrix above is the special case when $n=4$

Comment: if it is related to research question,you post there http://mathoverflow.net/questions