# Basis of a Subspace Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

$W = \{(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_4)\in R^4: x_1+x_3=x_4\}\\$
$$$$
I'm a bit confused about how to get the basis. I worked it out in terms of $x_4$ and got $$ x_4\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] -
       x_3\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] + 
       x_2\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] -
       x_1\left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$

So would the basis just be 
     $$\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] 
       \left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]  
       \left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right] 
       \left[\begin{array}{c}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$

Comment: This can not be a basis, since the dimension of $W$ is $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you know that solutions are of the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$, conditioned to

$$x_1 + x_3 = x_4$$

Hence, you'd know that solutions are of the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_1 + x_3)$, which means you can rewrite it as

$$(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_1 + x_3) = x_1(1, 0, 0, 1) + x_2(0, 1, 0, 0) + x_3(0, 0, 1, 1)$$

Hence, notice that any vector that is a solution is a linear combination of

$$\langle(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1)\rangle$$

Notice that such vectors are linearly independent, which means that it is also a basis for $W$

Answer (score 1):

The subspace $W$ consists of all vectors $\mathbf{x}$ that satisfy:
$$
x_{1} +x_{3} = x_{4}
\Leftrightarrow
x_{1} +x_{3} -x_{4}= 0
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0 & 1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
\mathbf{x} = 0.
$$
That is, $W$ contains all vectors that are in the nullspace of $\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0 & 1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}$.
All you have to do now, is find a basis for the nullspace: [Finding the basis of a null space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/finding-the-basis-of-a-null-space)