# Calculating basis of null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have to get a basis and dimension for the null space of a matrix A:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -3 \\
        2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 6 \\
        3 & 4 & 3 & 6 & 5 & 8 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I attained the reduced row echelon form of the matrix:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & -6 & -2 & -13 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 9 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I know that the dimension of the null space is equal to the number of free variables, which in the case is $3$ (the last three columns). So, the dimension of the null space of $A$ is $3$.

I'm aware of this method for finding the null space: [Finding the basis of a null space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88301/finding-the-basis-of-a-null-space?rq=1)

However, I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around as to how I can apply it here as the $RREF(A)$ is a little more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always the same procedure. Consider the pivots in red.

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & -6 & -2 & -13 \\
        0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 3 & 2 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 4 & 1 & 9 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

We always write stuff based on the pivots. The first row would become:
$$x_1-6x_4-2x_5-13x_6=0\to x_1=6x_4+2x_5+13x_6$$

Similarly for row 2 and 3,

$$x_2+3x_4+2x_5+5x_6=0\to x_2=-3x_4-2x_5-5x_6$$

$$x_3+4x_4+x_5+9x_6=0\to x_3=-4x_4-x_5-9x_6$$

For row 4, there are no pivots, so we simply have $x_4=x_4$.

Notice that since we have $6$ columns, we do indeed have a $x_5$ and $x_6$, but similarly they are not pivots, and so $x_5 = x_5$, $x_6=x_6$.

Now, we can rewrite the system as the following:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        x_4 \\
        x_5 \\
        x_6
        \end{pmatrix}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        6x_4+2x_5+13x_6 \\
        -3x_4-2x_5-5x_6 \\
        -4x_4-x_5-9x_6 \\
        x_4 \\
        x_5 \\
        x_6 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = x_4\begin{pmatrix}
        6 \\
        -3 \\
        -4 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} + x_5 \begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        -2 \\
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} + x_6 \begin{pmatrix}
        13 \\
        -5 \\
        -9 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

So your basis for null space would be:

$$\{\begin{pmatrix}
        6 \\
        -3 \\
        -4 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        -2 \\
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} ,\begin{pmatrix}
        13 \\
        -5 \\
        -9 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\}$$

Answer (score 2):

The basis of the null space is very simple to achieve without any computation once the the matrix is in rref form.  Just equalize the matrix

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & -6 & -2 & -13 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 9 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
by adding three more rows, consisting of zeroes except for the row's number, here you fill in a $-1$:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & -6 & -2 & -13 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 9 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
Now exactly those column vectors containing the $-1$’s are a basis for the kernel of the matrix.

Edit:

If the matrix in rref is not already quadratic expand the matrix to a quadratic one as follows.  Each row of the matrix starts with a $1$.  Now if this $1$ is in position $k$, that row would be the $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ row of the expanded matrix.  To achieve the desired quadratic matrix fill up all the remaining lines by zeroes except of the row number's position: place a $-1$ there. If for example we have
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -13 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
start with
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
.&.&.&.&.&.\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -13 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\
.&.&.&.&.&.\\
.&.&.&.&.&.\\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now fill in the gaps:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0&0&0&0\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 & -13 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\
0&0&0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&-1\\
        \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now the column vectors which contain the $-1$'s, that is the first, and fifth ant sixth of that matrix are a basis for the kernel of the matrix.

Comment: How does this work? Do we just multiply by -1 all other entries and make the -1 to 1?