# Prove a list of vectors are basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{5}$ such that

$$U = \{(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5): (6z_1 = z_2)\wedge(z_3+2z_4+3z_5=0)\}$$

Find a basis of $U$.

Here is what I came up with:

**Claim**: $(1,6,0,0,0),(0,0,-2,1,0),(0,0,-3,0,1)$ is a basis.

Now I can see that the above list of vectors is a basis but I don't know how to start by proving it.

Here is what I have tried:

WTS for all $z\in U$, $z = a_1(1,6,0,0,0) + a_2(0,0,-2,1,0) + a_3(0,0,-3,0,1)$, forall $a_i\in\mathbb{F}$.

So let $z\in U$, then
\begin{align*}
z & = (z_1,6z_1,z_3,z_4,z_5)\\\\
& = (z_1,6z_1,0,0,0)+(0,0,-2z_4,z_4,0) + (0,0,-3z_5,0,z_5)\\\\
& = z_1(1,6,0,0,0)+z_4(0,0,-2,1,0)+z_5(0,0,-3,0,1)
\end{align*}

But this doesn't seem right, unless $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88301/10575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
U = \{(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5): (6z_1 = z_2)\wedge(z_3+2z_4+3z_5=0)\}
$$

For any vector $z \in U$, we find that
$$
z_2 = 6 z_1
$$
and
$$
z_3 = -2 z_4 - 3 z_5
$$

Hence, it follows that
$$
z = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
z_1 \\
z_2 \\
z_3 \\
z_4 \\
z_5 \\
\end{array} \right] =
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
z_1 \\
6 z_1 \\
- 2 z_4 - 3 z_5 \\
z_4 \\
z_5 \\
\end{array} \right] =
z_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + z_4 \mathbf{v}_2 + z_5 \mathbf{v}_3
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{v}_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
6 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{array} \right], \ \
\mathbf{v}_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
-2 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{array} \right], \ \
\mathbf{v}_3 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\
0 \\
-3 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

Since $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3$ are linearly independent, we conclude that
$$
\mathcal{B} = \{ \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3 \}
$$
is a basis for $U$. Hence, $\mbox{dim}(U) = 3$.